# Locating elements directly inside a dictionary or json object using multiple properties with Python

Tags: python, json

All i am a bit new to python and more so have background in other languages.  My specific question is what is the easiest way to get to location within a dictionary or json document by using multiple properties of each doc entry.

Example doc structure:

```
[
   {"Car" : "Ford", "Color" : "Red", "ID" : 1},
   {"Car" : "Ford", "Color" : "Blue", "ID" : 2},   
]
```

Is there an easy way to say search for a Red Ford using something other than having to write a iteration function unique to each doc to locate those records?

```
print (doc["Ford"]["Red"]) 

or something similar to how a SQL works in a database like 

Select * from doc where Car='Ford' and Color='Red'
```

Just starting down the python path with multiple document structures and want to make sure i'm not doing something more crudely than it needs to be.  I know the iteration will of course work but you have to kinda code one for each document and it just seems like there would be something simpler but not sure.

Thanks!

Tim

Comment: Since you have a _list_ of dictionaries, you will certainly have to iterate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could utilize an array filter based on your current example:

```
[o for o in doc if o["Car"] == "Ford" and o["Color"] == "Red"]
```

Alternatively, `filter`:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x["Car"] == "Ford" and x["Color"] == "Red", doc))
```

Comment: Thanks... i will work on something like this!   Appreciate it.